# Как вызвать write contract в модульном блокчейне

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3.py

Есть контракт в модульном (совместимый с Evm блокчейн) на примере Mantle
контракт 0x7C78b18F496d3D37c44De09da4a5a76Eb34B7e74

в нем есть метод MintMJ(0x986d8002)
Call mintMJ(address receiver, uint256 id, uint64 expirationDate, string schema, string attestationURL, bytes signature)
Значения Data
receiver 0x...
id 0
expirationDate 0
schema пустая строка
attestationURL 14k78a3c-1c15-44be-53a0-36bbd0288b2c
signature 0x..

Как я могу отправить транзакцию с помощью python. Сколько не пытаюсь сгенирировать rawData все время получаются другие данные, подозреваю что дело в -

[image]